# How can I get resource Id from String value(not name)

Tags: android

I want get Resource id from String 'value', not 'name'

**String.xml**

```
....
<string name="str_name">strValue</string>    
....
```

like this :

```
// I want get [str_name]'s id value.
// this code return 0.
int stringId = getResources().getIdentifier("strValue", "id", "com.test.test");
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Reverse lookup I think is not possible. Because values are not unique identifier

Comment: No idea . Didn't find any answer yet

Comment: Answers next, first can we know why did you get this strange thought? May be there is some better approach to do what you are trying but for that we need to know what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, you can. Please read the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no method to lookup by value as it is not guaranteed to be unique. You need to iterate over all i.e. strings and compare values yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using 'R.string.str_name' this will return the id of the resource, but IMHO you should go with the standard approach and avoid using auto-generated Ids. Thank You.

Code:

```
int stringId = R.string.str_name;
```